# Dynamically redraw re sized circle in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, drawrect

What im trying to do is have a user touch the screen, when the touch is detected at the position the circle is meant to grow in size (and keep growing) until the user lets go.

I know how to detect touches but the problem im having is trying to draw and have the circle re drawn as its getting larger.

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: See following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724787/animating-a-circle-to-grow

Comment: are you using a custom view for the circle that can be invalidated?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a combination of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, `NSTimer`, and `UIBezierPath` to achieve this.

First, set up your `viewDidLoad` to add and configure the CAShapeLayer that will house the circle you wish to draw. The following code will initially draw a circle on screen with a radius of 50 points, and add a long press gesture to the main view. Of course the touch detection can be done in what ever way you'd like. Oh, and you'll need to import Quartz for this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    circleRadius = 50.0f;

    circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    [circle setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
    [circle setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [circle setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:0.7f].CGColor];
    [circle setLineWidth:5.0f];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

    [self drawCircleWithRadius:circleRadius];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
    [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:0.1];
    [longPress setAllowableMovement:15.0f];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}
```

Then, when the long press gesture is recognized, check its state. If its state is *began* start a repeating timer to call the animation function. When the gesture ends, invalidate.

```
- (void)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(animateImageView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

- (void)animateImageView {
    circleRadius += 10.0f;
    [self drawCircleWithRadius:circleRadius];
}
```

And finally, this function below will use a CABasicAnimation animate the path property of the shape layer to the value indicated above (+10 every time). Make sure that this animations duration isn't higher than the timers repeats interval!

```
- (void)drawCircleWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    [pathAnimation setFromValue:(id)circle.path];
    [pathAnimation setToValue:(id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0f * radius, 2.0f * radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath];
    [pathAnimation setDuration:0.1];
    [pathAnimation setRepeatCount:1.0f];
    [pathAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius, CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);
    [circle addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"changePathAnimation"];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use Quartz 2D and animate the shape on touch.

Use something like this..

[image]

```
CGContextRef ctxt = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGGradientRef gradient;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
CGFloat locations[] = {0.0,1.0};
CGFloat components[] = { 0.5,1.0,1.0,1.0, 0.25,0.5,0.5,1.0 };
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace,components,locations,
                                               sizeof(locations)/sizeof(CGFloat));
CGPoint start = {70.0,130.0}, end = {100.0,100.0};
CGFloat startRadius = 0.0, endRadius = 90.0;
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctxt,gradient,start,startRadius,end,endRadius,0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Found more information here.. 
[In iOS Development, using Core Graphics and/or Quartz 2D, how can I draw a circle filled with a gradient in such a manner that it looks like a sphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638934/in-ios-development-using-core-graphics-and-or-quartz-2d-how-can-i-draw-a-circl)

Also for the animation techniques with Quartz2d please look here..
https://github.com/neror/CA360

Comment: Sorry @Brent French, i need to redraw the circle. Please check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

You have to custom UIView to draw the circle in the drawRect: method. Handle a pinch effect on the view of your viewController, update the variable in the UIView custom and use :

```
[myCicleView setNeedsDisplay];
```

to  force the view to redraw itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Touch** methods

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(reDrawCircle) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [myTimer invalidate];
   myTimer = nil;
}
```

For Scalling Image::

```
-(void)reDrawCircle {

   //Your Code for Circle Re-Draw.
}
```

When user touches, it'll start timer for your method for re drawing circle and when User ends with touch, it'll invalidate timer. So it'll not call method for re-draw.

Hopefully, it'll help you.
Thanks.